# Finding the Roots of a Polynomial with Vieta's Formulas

Tags: polynomials

$\alpha \ and\  \beta$ are two roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$
Prove that $\alpha\beta$ is a root of $x^3-bx^2+acx-c^2=0$

Do you use Vieta's formulas?

Comment: Did you use them?

Comment: Anyway, this problem is just an istance of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789246/given-two-algebraic-conjugates-alpha-beta-and-their-minimal-polynomial-find

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$. My claim is that
$$ x^3-bx^2+acx-c^2 = (x-\alpha\beta)(x-\alpha\gamma)(x-\beta\gamma) \tag{1}$$
that boils down to proving that $b=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma$ (trivial by Vieta's formulas), that $c^2=\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma^2$ (again, trivial by Vieta's formulas) and that
$$ ac = \alpha^2\beta\gamma+ \alpha\beta^2\gamma+\alpha\beta\gamma^2 \tag{2}$$
trivial again, since the RHS of $(2)$ is $(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\alpha\beta\gamma = ac$.